# How to join multiple foreign keys that points to single primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

Dears,

I have two separate sql statements below. Independently they work fine.

```
select teams.team_name_eng AS "TNAME1"
from matches, teams
where matches.team1_uid = teams.tid;

select teams.team_name_eng AS "TNAME2"
from matches, teams
where matches.team2_uid = teams.tid
```

How can i combine those statements into one statement? I want the output to be

```
TNAM1     TNAME2
-----     ------
playerA   PlayerB
playerC   playerD
```

Note: foreign-key relationships already created.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Join to get the answer

```
select teams1.team_name_eng AS "TNAME1",teams2.team_name_eng AS "TNAME2"
from matches
join teams as teams1 on teams1.tid = matches.team1_uid
join teams as teams2 on teams2.tid = matches.team2_uid
```

Comment: there is no teams2.tid. only teams.uid

Comment: your answer worked for me, can you please explain what is the purpose of "as teams1" in join syntax?

Comment: We join the same table twice, So we added the alies name for the table

Answer (score 1):

You have to use alias for your table :

```
select teams_1.team_name_eng AS "TNAME1", teams_2.team_name_eng AS "TNAME2"
from matches, teams as teams_1, teams as teams_2
where matches.team1_uid = teams_1.tid
AND matches.team2_uid = teams_2.tid ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use join twice with different alias

```
select t.team_name_eng AS "TNAME1", t1.team_name_eng AS "TNAME2"
from matches inner join teams t on matches.team1_uid = t.tid
inner join teams t1 on matches.team2_uid = t1.tid
```

Answer (score 1):

basic join
join the same table twice, each time with a different key:

```
select t.team_name_eng AS "TNAME1",
t2.team_name_eng AS "TNAME2"
from matches m
LEFT JOIN teams t ON m.team1_uid = t.tid
LEFT JOIN teams t2 ON m.team2_uid = t.tid
;
```

Answer (score 1):

use teams table in join 2 times , 1 for team1_uid and another for  team2_uid

```
  select t.team_name_eng AS TNAME1,t1.team_name_eng as TNAME2
    from  matches m join  teams t
    on  m.team1_uid = t.tid
    join teams t1
        and m.team2_uid = t1.tid
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query you might be looking for.

```
select teams.team_name_eng AS "TNAME1", teams.team_name_eng AS "TNAME2"
from matches, teams as teams_1, teams as teams_2 where matches.team1_uid = teams_1.tid
AND matches.team2_uid = teams_2.tid ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this query

```
Select t.team_name_eng as"TNAME1", t2.team_name_eng as "TNAME2" from matches m  join teams t on m.team1_uid = t.tid join teams t2 on m.team2_uid = t2.tid
```

Comment: there is no t2.tid

Comment: Please have a look